# How to get value from input with Blur() inside of change event in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a form that is using a change event to handle a method. One of the inputs is causing an error though because it is reading the value before the user is finished adding value. Is there a way to make inputvalue1's value have a blur function attached, so the value isn't read after each letter is typed? I can't make the whole thing a on Blur because then the date picker won't trigger the method.

```
    <form
      :items=item
      :key="formItem.id"
      @change="handleChange"
    >

const handleChange = () => {
 const inputValue1 = form.value[inputOne].toUpperCase()
 const inputDate = form.value[inputTwo]
if(inputValue1 === 'Something'){
  inputDate = '12/12'21'
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am not quite clear with the problem, but from what I understood you can define a variable and on the basis of value of the variable read the form input value in the inputValue1.

Comment: I don't want the change event to trigger on const inputValue1 until the user has removed focus from the input. But I need the inputDate to be a change event because of the datepicker. Since they are both used in the same method, I need to add a blur function to the  const inputValue1

Comment: add an argument of `event` to the `handleChange` function. It should have the `type` property which you can check if it's `blur` and perform any additional logic at that point.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy how do i check if event type blur? if(event[type].blur.inputValue1 === 'Something')?

Comment: `event.target` will have the element in question and `event.type` will have the event in question, based on these 2 properties you should be able to determine the appropriate conditional

Comment: https://www.cloudhadoop.com/vuejs-input-blur-event-handler#google_vignette